# Page 17. Kashiwara's Categories & Sheaves equivalent statement to $F: C \times C' \to C''$ is a bifunctor.

Tags: category-theory

[Here's the book.](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kashiwara2.pdf) The book says:

> A functor $F: \mathcal{C}\times \mathcal{C}'\to \mathcal{C}''$ is called a bifunctor.  This is equivalent to saying that for $X \in \mathcal{C}$ and $X'\in \mathcal{C}', F(X, \cdot): \mathcal{C}'\to \mathcal{C}''$ and $F(\cdot, X'): \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}''$ are functors. [...]

However, how do you prove that $F(X, \text{id}_{X'}) = \text{id}_{F(X, X')}$ for every $X$ in $\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$?

Comment: $F(X, -)$ is a functor, so it sends identities to identities. What is the problem?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan how is $F(X, \cdot)$ defined so that it *does* map identities to identities.  I think I have an answer to this.

Comment: if $F(-, -) : C \times C' \to C''$ is a bifunctor and $X \in C$ is an object, then $F(X, -)$ is the composition of $F(-, -)$ with the functor $C' \times C \times C'$ given on objects by $X' \mapsto (X, X')$ and doing the obvious things to morphisms.

Comment: Obviously there's a typo in last Qiaochu Yuan's comment: it should be "with the functor $C' \to C \times C'$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we're supposed to define $F(X, f) = F(\text{id}_X \times f)$.  Then $F(X, \text{id}_{X'})$ does equal identity.

And $F(X, f\circ g) = F(\text{id}_X \times (f \circ g)) = F((\text{id}_X \times f) \circ (\text{id}_X \times g))$

and since $F$ is a functor:
$$ \dots = F(X,f) \circ F(X,g)
$$

Comment: Probably you rather mean $F(X,f)=F(\mathrm{id}_X,\,f)$,